# I need to remove all . that don't match a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove all dots from text unless they match a pattern [0-9]+.[0-9]+
for example if the following text is my input:

```
abc. def. 123.45 ... 12.
```

the output should look like this:

```
abc def 123.45 12
```

Thanks

Comment: Which language/tool do you use?

Comment: What patterns have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language you are using supports [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can use this regular expression:

```
(?<![0-9])\.|\.(?![0-9])
```

This matches dots that either aren't preceded by a digit, or aren't followed by a digit.

Example for C#:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<![0-9])\.|\.(?![0-9])", "");
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/uMJFWu)

Answer (score 0):

If your regex flavor supports negative lookarounds (which .NET does fabulously) you can use this:

```
(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)
```

This will only match dots that have either a non-digit character before or after them. Simply replace the result with an empty string.

If not, then you can do this:

```
(?|(^|\D)\.|\.($|\D))
```

And replace with `$1`. This does the same, but includes that additional character in the match. The replacement puts that matched character back in place.